# C: How to extract numbers from string without strtol

Tags: c, numbers, extract

I have problem with extracting numbers from string.
Problem is I can **not use strtol or isdigit** functions as teacher requested so.
I am supposed to save numbers in **new array**.
For example, string input:

> 11-some12meh13text-14

.
So new array would be:

> 11,12,13,14

**(NOT -14)**
I came to idea to do following:

```
char str1[150];
int array[20];
int temporary, i=0, j=0; //i - for string, j - for array

for(i=0;i<=strlen(str1);i++) {
    if(i==0) { //not needed to check if char before was number
        if((str1[i]>=0) && (str1[i]<=9))temporary=str1[i];
        if((str1[i+1]<=0) && (str1[i+1]>=9)) {//if next char is NOT number
            array[j]=temporary;
            j++;
        }
    }
    else if(i!=0) { //needs to be checked if char before was number
        if((str1[i]>=0) && (str1[i]<=9)) {
            if((str1[i-1]>=0) && (str1[i-1]<=9))temporary=temporary*10+str1[i];
            else temporary=str1[i];
            if((str1[i+1]<=0) && (str1[i+1]>=9)) {//if next char is NOT number
                array[j]=temporary;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it on my PC, but program crashes and I have no idea or ability to find what I did wrong.
Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Change `>=0` to `>='0'` and `<=9` to `<='9'`. And of course, `temporary=str1[i]` to `temporary=str1[i]-'0'`.

Comment: One tip: do not keep writing `str1[i] >= 0 && str1[i] <= 9`.  Write a function, call it `my_isdigit` (or something like that) and call it.  And, instead of comparing to `0` and `9`, you'll want to compare to `'0'` and `'9'`

Comment: I look stupid now, making those basic mistakes. Thank you guys, it works now! :)

Comment: Not stupid: be thankful it was such a small mistake.

Comment: Please, when posting code, post code that compiles.

Comment: @user3629249 Why? I can post whole program but it has about 150 lines, because this is only part of 1 big program. And I don't think that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral values of characters `'0'...'9'` are not `0...9`.

Hence, change every occurrence of `str1[k]` to `str1[k]-'0'`.

Comment: Why would I do that? Why removing 1?

Comment: @MatejVeličan: Sorry, missed out that extra letter. The point was to subtract the value of `'0'`.

Comment: so should I replace also every str1[k+1] by adding -'0'  (also k-1) ?

Comment: setting values into the array is not the same as stepping through the array.  so make the fixes as suggested, and do not tweak the array values when stepping through the array.

Comment: @MatejVeličan: You're not using `k` in your code, right? I used it as a general index, so it goes for `i`, `i-1`, and any other subscript that you're using in order to read this array. And in either case, **do not write** into this array, if that's what you meant to ask.

Comment: No, no, I know you were using k in general. Thank you. But what do you mean by that I shouldn't write into array? That's my task given by teacher. To save numbers in array.

Comment: @MatejVeličan: I meant, don't write into the `str1` array.

Answer (score 1):

If using `sscanf()` is allowed, this will parse the string for integers. The `%n` specifier will report the number of characters processed by the scan. This lets you move through the string.
When the scan for an integer fails ( != 1), the scanset `"%*[^0-9\n]%n"` scans and discards characters that are not a digit or newline. The `%n` captures the number of characters processed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( ) {
    char str1[150] = {"0+1-=2!3*4-5/6#7&8|9^10"};
    int array[20] = {0};
    int offset = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int used = 0;
    int length = 0;

    length = strlen ( str1);
    do {
        sscanf ( str1 + offset, "%*[^0-9\n]%n", &used);
        offset += used;
        if ( ( sscanf ( str1 + offset, "%d%n", &array[each], &used)) == 1) {
            offset += used;
            each++;
            if ( each >= 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( offset < length);

    for ( loop = 0; loop < each; loop++) {
        printf ( "%d\n", array[loop]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a version of your code that seems to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( ) {
    char str1[150] = {"-0+1-=2!3*4-text-5/6#7&8|9^10 11end"};
    int array[20] = {0};
    int each = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int saved = 1;
    int length = 0;
    int temporary = 0, i=0;

    length = strlen ( str1);
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if ( ( str1[i] >= '0') && ( str1[i] <= '9')) {//found a digit
            temporary = ( temporary * 10) + ( str1[i] - '0');
            saved = 0;//flag not saved. temporary value may change
        }
        else {//found NOT a digit
            if ( i > 0 && !saved) {//not at first character and not saved
                array[each] = temporary;//save integer
                each++;
                saved = 1;//flag saved
                temporary = 0;//reset
                if ( each >= 20) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( !saved && each < 19) {//end of string is an integer. save it
        array[each] = temporary;
        each++;
    }
    for ( loop = 0; loop < each; loop++) {
        printf ( "%d\n", array[loop]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not working if you have * or / before number. Probably some more signs

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Not even my teacher knows what is the problem with thing I coded myself.